# Does anyone know how to connect to a terminal services gateway using a RDP V6 compatible client in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: command-line, rdp, services

Right now the only reason I have windows installed ( on it's own drive ) is that I need to connect to my computer at work and it's behind a TS gateway.
Does anyone know of a RDP v6 compatible client for Ubuntu that can be configured for such a task?

Answer (score 1):

A good command line client that is RDPv6 compatible is rdesktop. Rdesktop can be installed with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install rdesktop
```

From there you can connect to a server by following these directions:
http://linux.die.net/man/1/rdesktop

There are many front ends available for rdesktop too, such as Gnome-RDP.

Comment: Sadly, rdesktop doesn't appear to support v6